# How can i make border in the second page in GridView in Print?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem - when i want to print my page with gridview with header - second page is printing without header border. I make pagebreaker to prevent this , but it still cutting .
I have situation like this : 
[image]

But i want border on header too , like this:
[image]

My code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
       <title></title>
        <link href="../Content/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="window.print(); window.close();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  HeaderStyle-BorderColor="Black" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"   DataSourceID="DSInsertNewDoc">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="sgq" HeaderText="asd" SortExpression="sgq" HtmlEncode="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="f1" HeaderText="adad" SortExpression="f1" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="2" HeaderText="dgdghdh" SortExpression="2" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="3" HeaderText="asdaeg" SortExpression="3" />
                   ...
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSD" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Context %>" SelectCommand="2018S" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:SessionParameter Name="MCOD" SessionField="MCOD" Type="String" />
 </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebehind :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
DSD.SelectParameters["mcod"].DefaultValue = Request["MCOD"];

            DSD.DataBind();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                counter = counter + 1;
                if (counter % 10 == 0)
                {
                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("style" , "page-break-after: always;border-collapse:collapse;" );
                    GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
                    GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are your screenshots correct? There's not really much of a difference between the 2 pictures that I can see

Comment: @abney317 i changed it